# Rebounding projectile?

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

how would I rebound a projectile when it touches falls outside of the screen?

My code:
http://pastebin.com/qs3kyaTc

I have Box2d Installed as well as cocos2d, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have collision detection?

Comment: Yes i do. Its detected on the exit of the screen, well when it touches the edges.

Comment: When it reaches the +/- max X walls, negate the X velocity. When it reaches the +/- max Y walls, negate the Y velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rebound a projectile off of objects, normally you need to find the reflection vector `r` (the unit normal vector of your surface). Then take your unit velocity vector `v`, and set your final velocity to

`r +  (r - v)`

Assuming that your surfaces are perfectly vertical or horizontal, that means if your projectile bounces off of one wall only, If it bounces off of a wall that is facing the `x` direction, just negate the `x` component of your velocity. If it bounces off of a wall that is facing the `y` direction, just negate the `y` component of your velocity. If your projectile is found to collide with two walls at the same time, then negate both.